# unknown type name 'clockid_t'

Tags: c, macos, timer, posix

I am trying to use C code written on a Linux platform on Mac OS X. I am running into an error related to timers:

```
../src/stinger/timer.c:61:1: error: unknown type name 'clockid_t'
../src/stinger/timer.c:74:2: error: #error "Cannot find a clock!"
```

which points to this section of code.

```
 static clockid_t clockid;

#if defined(CLOCK_REALTIME_ID)
#define CLKID CLOCK_REALTIME_ID
#define CLKIDNAME "CLOCK_REALTIME_ID"
#elif defined(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID)
#define CLKID CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
#define CLKIDNAME "CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID"
#elif defined(CLOCK_REALTIME_ID)
#warning "Falling back to realtime clock."
#define CLKID CLOCK_REALTIME_ID
#define CLKIDNAME "CLOCK_REALTIME_ID"
#else
#error "Cannot find a clock!"
#endif
```

What is the cause of this error? Where should the type `clockid_t` come from?

Comment: From `time.h`, but the feature test macro requirement is `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L`. If you compile with e.g. `-std=c99`, that isn't set.

Comment: I compile with `-std=c99`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L` on the command line for example, or you can `#define` it in the file before `#include <time.h>`. I'm not sure, maybe compiling with `-gnu99` would also set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly all the "clock" stuff is part of the "realtime" extension of POSIX that isn't implemented by OSX. So you will not have luck with that. You'd have to use OSX specific features to have a clock at a good resolution.

*Edit:* In [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) I have a wrapper code for OSX for the similar C11 function `timespec_get`. No Idea if this really functional, I don't have a Mac, but you could have a look, there. (file is "p99_threads.h")

Comment: Here's how a developer of the code commented on this issue:
> librt houses the timers as a non-historical piece.  Apple
"thought different" about standards and did something else.
You'll see these errors after fixing the above (or using make
-k... oh, wait, it's a Mac).  See the Graph500 code for one timer
version.  Someone no doubt has a POSIX-compliant wrapper around
Apple's timers somewhere.