# C++ - Loop with fixed delta time on a background POSIX Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, posix

The goal is to call a function on a background thread with a fixed delta Time.

The function should get called 60 times / second, hence at timestamps 0, 0.0166, etc. The timestamps should be hit as precisely as possible.

The simple but probably not best solution would be to run a while(true)-loop and let the thread sleep until the next time the function should be called. Here's half C++ / half pseudo-Code how it'd do it.

```
float fixedDeltaTime = 1.0 / 60.0;
void loopFunction() 
{
      while(true)
      {
         auto currentTime = getTime();
         // do work
         auto timePassed = getTime() - currentTime;
         int times = (timePassed / fixedDeltaTime);
         sleep(  (fixedDeltaTime * times) - timePassed)
      }
}

int main()
{
   std::thread loopFunction(call_from_thread);
   return 0;
}
```

Yesterday, I asked this very same question asking for a solution using C++11 std::thread. Some people in the comments told me that using POSIX thread would be better. Though pthreads seem even more complicated to me, so I hope somebody here can show me how to solve this issue with pthreads.

Comment: Is there any reason why your current solution isn't good enough?

Comment: Well, yes. std::sleep_for is not very accurate, so I have to do it in very tiny intervals and check if the time to call loopFunction() has already been come. In the other thread people also said the chrono time measurement is very expensive.

Comment: @keyboard - since I am guilty of mentioning that timers may be costly, what is the actual delta time that will be used ? If it really is 0.0166 don't mind my comment on the timer performance (unless  you are launching 100 parallel threads). Again, if you really want performance, use the native waitable timer on each platform, but I think that is overkill for such a big timeout.

Comment: If you want *very* accurate timing without writing kernel level code you probably have to dedicate a core to the worker and let it run without waits/sleeps and use a perf counter to track ns or ms to trigger when you need it...

Comment: Well, I'm now using an interval of 1.0 / 600.0 seconds and I need only 1 thread.  But I'm not only asking because you said the thing about performance. It's also about learning how to do it with pthread.

Comment: Check the `timer_create()` POSIX function. The behavior is largely platform specific. On Linux it is said that there are clock sources with high resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Posix Threads surely grant faster communication among foreground and background tasks, but if you want **precision** I would suggest using **clock_nanosleep** to keep track of time on top of a real time kernel.

You can use the following base functions to shape your task life-cycle:

```
#ifndef __TIMERS_H__
#define __TIMERS_H__

#include <stdint.h>  /* uint64_t                           */
#include <time.h>    /* clockid_t of clock_nanosleep()     */

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Common facility functions needed for
 * high precision timers usage
 */

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define SEC_VAL 1000000000ULL

enum return_values {
    RETURN_FAILURE = 0,
    RETURN_SUCCESS = 1,
    RETURN_EMPTY = 2
};

typedef void* timespec_ptr;

typedef struct timespec timespec_t;

/* Adds time_us microseconds to timer ts
 */
void timespec_add_ns(timespec_ptr ts,
        uint64_t time_ns);
/* Makes the thread wait for the next activation of the timer ts
 */
void wait_next_activation(timespec_ptr ts); /*** @ Tasks ***/
/* Starts the periodic timer
 */
int start_periodic_timer(timespec_ptr ts,
        uint64_t init_offs_ns);

/* Computes the difference among two clocks
 */
long calcdiff(struct timespec t1,
        struct timespec t2);

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

extern int clock_nanosleep(clockid_t clock_id, int flags,
                           const struct timespec* request,
                           struct timespec* remain);

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#endif
```

Here you have the implementation file:

```
#include "timers.h"
#include <stdio.h> /* fprintf */

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Adds time_us microseconds to timer ts
 */
void timespec_add_ns(timespec_ptr ts,
        uint64_t time_ns)
{
    if (ts)
    {
        timespec_t* ts_ = (timespec_t*) ts;

        time_ns += ts_->tv_nsec;
        ts_->tv_sec += time_ns/SEC_VAL;
        ts_->tv_nsec = time_ns%SEC_VAL;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning (%s): input argument is NULL, \
                         request ignored.\n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
}

/* Makes the thread wait for the next activation of the timer ts
 */
void wait_next_activation(timespec_ptr ts)
{
    if (ts)
    {
        timespec_t* ts_ = (timespec_t*) ts;

        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, ts_, NULL);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning (%s): input parameter is NULL, \
                         request ignored.\n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
}

/* Starts the periodic timer
 */
int start_periodic_timer(timespec_ptr ts,
        uint64_t init_offs_ns) /*** @ Tasks ***/
{
    if (ts)
    {
        timespec_t* ts_ = (timespec_t*) ts;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ts_);
        timespec_add_ns(ts, init_offs_ns);
        return RETURN_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning (%s): input parameter is NULL, \
                         request ignored.\n", __FUNCTION__);
        return RETURN_FAILURE;
    }
}

/* Computes the difference among two clocks
 */
long calcdiff(struct timespec t1,
        struct timespec t2) /*** @ Tasks ***/
{
    long diff;

    diff = SEC_VAL * ((int) t1.tv_sec - (int) t2.tv_sec);
    diff += ((int) t1.tv_nsec - (int) t2.tv_nsec);
    return diff;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

The background-task should basically do the following:

```
void run (void *args) {
    start_periodict_timer(&timer_, offset);
    while (true) {
        wait_next_activation(&timer_);
        timespec_add_ns(&timer_, period);

        /* do your periodic task */

    }
}
```

where **offset** is the initial time you wait since when you start the task, and **period** is the amount of time you wait in-between one invocation of the task and another.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like I cannot use this. I'm getting clockid_t (and more) not declared/found. Apparently these things are not there on iOS and OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472761/unknown-type-name-clockid-t

Comment: @keyboard thanks for highlighting this limitation. Have you tried using nanosleep()/usleep() on iOS, if available()?